# How to send data from Java method to java script function?

Tags: javascript, java, spring, rest, intellij-idea

I have created a pop up window using Java script. I want to display a string on that pop up window which is returned from a Java method. I have created a controller and mapped the parameters. But the string is not displaying correctly.

Here is my java script function which displays the pop up window but string value is not showing up.

```
<script>

function myFunction() {

    alert(${random_number});
}
</script>
```

Here is the java method which I want to take the string generated.

```
public class VerificationCode {

final static int numOfDigits = 4;
String PINString = "";
int randomPIN = 0;

public  String RandomNumber() {

    for(int i = 0; i<numOfDigits; i++){
        randomPIN = (int)(Math.random() * 8) + 1;
        PINString = PINString+String.valueOf(randomPIN);
    }

    return PINString;
}
```

}

This is the controller I wrote. I wonder whether this is correct since I have less experience with this.

```
public class PopupController {

@RequestMapping(value = "/register-login", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String viewUserRegistrationPage(ModelMap model) {
    VerificationCode vc = new VerificationCode();
    String print_val = vc.RandomNumber();
    model.addAttribute("random_number", print_val);
    //return "text";
    return "user-management";
}
```

}

What I want to do is display the string value "PINString" on the pop up window created using java script function "myFunction()". I use IntelliJ as my IDE and JBoss server.

edited:
relevant HTML form

```
<div class="form-group">
<div class="col-sm-8 col-sm-offset-4 col-md-offset-4" onclick="myFunction()">
<input type="submit" value="Register"
class="btn btn-primary btn-flat w-min-120"
data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal"/>                                                          
</div>
 <input type="hidden" id="myInput" value="${random_number}">
 <script>

//When the user clicks on div, open the popup
function myFunction() {
//var str = VerificationCode.RandomNumber();
alert("myInput");
}
   </script>
</div>
```

Comment: In your HTML store the value in a `hidden` HTML element - use jquery or javascript to read and display this value

Comment: @ScaryWombat Not clear. Which value should I store

Comment: `model.addAttribute("random_number", print_val);` - so using JSTL something like `${random_number}`

Comment: I wrote this on my html.

Comment: so what?  What are you meaning?

Comment: I wrote this on my html. <input type="hidden" id="myInput" value=${random_number}>  and input the value "myinput" to the javascript function. Now I get an error as "Error processing request"

Comment: does not the `value` need to be quoted?  `value="${random_number}"`

Comment: Error still persists. I will put the code as an edit in the question

Comment: No idea what this *Now I get an error as "Error processing request"* means

Comment: @ScaryWombat when I deployed my code browser says "Error processing request"

Comment: Yeah, but where does this message come from?  Check that your server-side is not throwing an exception

Answer (score 0):

I guess you need to update your JS function:

```html
<script type="text/javascript">  
  function myFunction(){  
    var number=document.getElementById("myInput").getAttribute("value");  
    alert(number);  
  }  
</script>
```

In html page should be included jstl tag and added expression:

```
<c:out value='${random_number}'/>
```

HTML code:

```html
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"%>

<div class="form-group">
<div class="col-sm-8 col-sm-offset-4 col-md-offset-4" onclick="myFunction()">
<input type="submit" value="Register"
class="btn btn-primary btn-flat w-min-120"
data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal"/>                                                          
</div>
 <input type="hidden" id="myInput" value="<c:out value='${random_number}'/>">
 <script>

//When the user clicks on div, open the popup
function myFunction() {
//var str = VerificationCode.RandomNumber();
alert("myInput");
}
   </script>
</div>
```

Comment: Probably error is in your Java controller or HTML/JSTL syntax. Could you paste error stack trace?

Comment: Context Path:/adsops
Servlet Path:/user-management/register-login
Path Info:null
Query String:null
Stack Trace

Comment: In html page at first line need to import jstl tag:
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"%>

Input element code should look like:
<input type="hidden" id="myInput" value="<c:out value='${random_number}'/>">

Comment: the `c:out` tag is not necessary